# How to make a tuple from two indices in a list of lists?

Tags: list, functional-programming, f#

I currently have a list that contains other lists inside. [ [1, 2, 3]; [9, 8, 7];...]

I would like to create a list of tuples from two indices in one of these 3 element lists I have stored inside of the entire list.

I have written something like

```
let makeTuple list = 
  let rec tuple list tuplesList = 
    match list with 
    | [] -> ()
    | h::t -> (tuple t ( (List.item 2 list, List.item 5 list)::tuplesList))

  tuple list []
```

When I run this function, it is giving me an error that there is an out of range index. I've tried other options but I can't seem to make sense of any of them. I'm new to F-sharp :-S. Any tips would be great.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, please at least provide an example of input and output.

Comment: It seems what you want may be `transpose` followed by `drop 2`, `take 1`, `drop 2`, `take 1`, and finally `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what output you are expecting. But this revision at least runs and returns a list of tuples, so maybe it is close to what you want.

```
let makeTuple list = 
  let rec tuple list tuplesList = 
    match list with 
    | [] -> tuplesList
    | h::t -> (tuple t ( (List.item 0 h, List.item 2 h)::tuplesList))

  tuple list []

let lst = [ [1; 2; 3]; [9; 8; 7]; [14; 15; 16]]

lst |> makeTuple
```

Output:

```
val makeTuple : list:'a list list -> ('a * 'a) list
val lst : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [9; 8; 7]; [14; 15; 16]]
val it : (int * int) list = [(14, 16); (9, 7); (1, 3)]
```